# How to filter/map an array in a data factory copy activity from a hierarchy JSON to tabular file?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

**The context**

I'm new to the Azure environment, so please bare with me if the question is simple. I have called a REST API with pagination. The data has multiple arrays stored in a hierachy. The arrays contains the same value translated in different languages. So in theory if I only want one language from that array the data is already in a tabular format. However, i'm having trouble with filtering the data to the correct language in the mapping part of the copy activity.

**Sample data**

Below is a sample of the data. I have added 3 different 'rows' for the tabular format. There are 3 different arrays in the data:

1. ['stage']['localization']
2. ['disqualifyReason']['localization']
3. ['title']['localization']

As I work for a dutch company, we only want the value where locale == 'nl-NL' to be returned.

```
[
    {
        "id": "f2597aa9-45b3-4142-a343-b1ec27fbfcea",
        "email": "some@email.com",
        "firstName": "Name",
        "lastName": "Name",
        "middleName": null,
        "created": "2023-01-03T13:29:15.7452993Z",
        "status": 1,
        "stage": {
            "localization":[
                {
                    "locale": "da-DK",
                    "value": "Ansøgt"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "de-DE",
                    "value": "Beworben"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "en-GB",
                    "value": "Applied"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "nl-NL",
                    "value": "Gesolliciteerd"
                }
            ]
        },
        "disqualifyReason": {
            "localization":[
                {
                    "locale": "nl-NL",
                    "value": "Geen match"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "da-DK",
                    "value": "Ikke et match"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "de-DE",
                    "value": "Absage - Screening"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "en-GB",
                    "value": "Not a match"
                }
            ]
        },
        "source":{
            "media":{
                "id": "c0772eab-09dd-4c7c-86b5-ee9b65ed8398", 
                "title": {
                    "localization":[
                        {
                            "locale": "nl-NL",
                            "value": "Tegel voor URL"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "a72b856e-8000-4e51-b475-9e6af5cf9e19",
        "email": "some@email.com",
        "firstName": "Name",
        "lastName": "Name",
        "middleName": null,
        "created": "2023-01-03T13:29:15.7452993Z",
        "status": 1,
        "stage": {
            "localization":[
                {
                    "locale": "nl-NL",
                    "value": "Afwijzen op CV"
                }
            ]
        },
        "disqualifyReason": null,
        "source":{
            "media":{
                "id": "c0772eab-09dd-4c7c-86b5-ee9b65ed8398", 
                "title": {
                    "localization":[
                        {
                            "locale": "nl-NL",
                            "value": "Tegel voor URL"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "f3898ebd-d6d6-4d9e-979e-348fe79325dc",
        "email": "some@email.com",
        "firstName": "Name",
        "lastName": "Name",
        "middleName": null,
        "created": "2023-01-03T14:36:04.4517426Z",
        "status": 1,
        "stage": {
            "localization":[
                {
                    "locale": "nl-NL",
                    "value": "1e interview"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "da-DK",
                    "value": "1. samtale"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "en-GB",
                    "value": "1st Interview"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "nl-NL",
                    "value": "1. Interview"
                }
            ]
        },
        "disqualifyReason": null,
        "source":{
            "media":{
                "id": "c0772eab-09dd-4c7c-86b5-ee9b65ed8398", 
                "title": {
                    "localization":[
                        {
                            "locale": "nl-NL",
                            "value": "Tegel voor URL"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**What did I try**

Lots of google, and microsoft learn pages. However, I thought the following dynamic function would work in the mapping part of the copy activity
`@filter($['stage']['localization']['locale'] == 'nl-NL')`, which it doens't. I can't use the filter function in the copy activity pipeline. I believe I can save the API call to a JSON file, then use data flows to filter it out in a data flow activity, which then stores it to a tabular format. However, isn't there a way to directly filter the data in the copy activity?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In copy activity mapping, there is a dynamic content option.

[image]

But **AFAIK**, **this will only apply to filter specific columns from source**. But in your case, you are trying to filter the records which might not be possible using copy activity.

> I believe I can save the API call to a JSON file, then use data flows
> to filter it out in a data flow activity, which then stores it to a
> tabular format.

Yes, using dataflows is the solution for it. And **dataflows also support REST API source. You can directly use dataflows and give pagination** like copy activity.

[image]

Then use filter transformation with your condition.

[image]

You will get the desired result in debug.